# Windows not booting, need help!

Tags: windows, uefi

I have a HP Pavillion G6 with Windows 8, and Ubuntu 12.10. After installing Ubuntu, Ubuntu didn´t startup, becauase Windows started up. So I did a repair with boot repair, but now Ubuntu is starting up, and not WIndows. The error is: error invalid EFI path.

Comment: Please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal in Ubuntu and type:

`sudo update-grub`.

Type a password if necessary. It will come up with this:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic 
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic 
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz.img-2.6.32-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-23-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Microsoft Windows 8 Pro on /dev/sda1
done
```

It might be different to you, like Windows might be on `sda2` instead of `sda1`. But still, in the text it verify's Windows 8. So it should solve your problems.

I did this with Win7, and it worked. I just copy and pasted the code and edited:

```
Found Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium on /dev/sda1
```

To:

```
Found Microsoft Windows 8 Pro on /dev/sda1
```

I typed up what it should say just in case if it doesn't say this. If there are any errors please reply back via comment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, by typing the things you said, it will be fixed? By the way: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5588058/

Comment: I did what you said, but Windows 8 is not starting. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5588058/

Comment: No that command does not change anything, just lists the bootable partitions/devices `Grub` detects. Please add the output of that command (`sudo update-grub`) into your question. We need to see which options are displayed by `Grub` and which one(s) you attempted (and failed) to boot Windows.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Boot Info Script output you posted shows a boatload of entries that *might* boot Windows. Try them all, especially `Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi`, `EFI/HP/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi`, and `EFI/HP/boot/bootmgfw.efi`.

If that doesn't work, try installing my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) The easiest way is to install the Debian package in Ubuntu. Given your configuration, you'll probably end up with a huge number of entries in its menu, at least one of which should work. You can then use the `dont_scan_dirs` and/or `dont_scan_files` options, or even delete unused boot files, to clean up the boot menu.